# Interpreting Seasonality Component Exponential Smoothing Models

Tags: r, time-series, seasonality, exponential-smoothing

I am building an exponential smoothing model that has seasonality in it, I would like to analyze the data with the seasonal factor removed so I can tell if a performance one month was due to seasonal factors or if it was just an over/under performing month.  I wanted to see if the approach I am taking makes sense or if I am widely off base.

For an example I looked at the Air Passengers data.  When using the ETS function it produces a MAM model and so then I look at the seasonal component.

```
library(datasets)
library(forecast)
fit <- ets(AirPassengers)
season <- fit$states[,"s1"]
```

I am going to use a bit of rounding for simplicity sake but let's say that for 1960 the first part of season is as follows:

```
Jan - 0.90
Feb - 0.89
Mar - 1.01
Apr - 0.99
....
```

Am I correct in interpreting this as January will be 10% lower due to seasonality factors, February 11% lower, March 1% higher, and April 1% lower?

If this is incorrect, is there a way to interpret the seasonality component in a similar way so that it can be "factored" out of other analysis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I correct in interpreting this as January will be 10% lower due to seasonality factors, February 11% lower, March 1% higher, and April 1% lower?

Yes. Given that your seasonality is *multiplicative* (the final "M" in the (M, Ad, M) model), this is exactly the correct interpretation. (If your seasonality were additive, you would need to interpret it as an additive offset.)